# How to find all the comment of a single author for the given data-set in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a blog dataset which looks like ths

```
{
    "_id" : "abcde",
    "author" : "xyz",
    "body" : "this is test body",
    "date" : "xyz",
    "tags" : ["tag1","tag2"],
    "comments":[
        { "body": "comment1",
          "email": "email1",
          "author" :"author1"
        },       
        { "body": "comment2",
          "email": "email2",
          "author" :"author2"
        }   
       ]
}
```

Here each document is representing a blog post. Each blog post can have multiple comments, but one my one user. Let's say I have to find all comments made by a particular author. What will be the query for that?

> One approach would be to unwind comments, then group by comments.author and push comments.body.

However, Can it be done without aggregation pipeline, just by using find? Because I think I am supposed to do it just by find. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dot notation to query against an array of subdocuments.

Your query would look something like this:

```
db.blog_posts.find({"comments.author": "author1"});
```

This will return all documents which contain subdocuments that have an author value of `author1`. The results will be the entire post document, so you might want to specify the fields that you want returned. This is called [query projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

db.blog_posts.find({"comments.author": "author1"});

To specify what fields you want, add an extra object as the second parameter to your `.find()` function:

```
db.blog_posts.find({"comments.author": "author1"}, {"comments": 1} );
```

Now the resulting documents will only contain the `_id` field and the `comments` field.

Keep in mind that you are actually querying the blog posts collection so your returned results will still be the blog posts - but only the ones where the specified author has commented on.

A simple way to take the next step and extract only the comment objects might look something like this:

```
var author = 'author1';
var comments = [];

db.blog_posts.find(...).forEach(function(doc){
  var post_comments = doc.comments;
  for (var i=0; i<post_comments.length; i++){
    if (post_comments[i].author ==  author){
      comments.push(post_comments[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

---

Here is the relevant documentation page:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#array-of-embedded-documents

> **Match a Field Without Specifying Array Index**
>   If you do not know the index position of the document in the array, concatenate the name of the field that contains the array, with a dot (.) and the name of the field in the embedded document.

Comment: Won't this query return all the blog post with comment by the author1? Because, I want all the comments by author1. The query will return more data than I need.

Comment: @Dude - you are correct, since you are querying the "blog posts" collection, the results you will get will be the posts themselves. I've added some extra parameters to only return the relevant data and not the entire blog entry.

Comment: @Dude - if you only want to use the `find()` function, you might have to iterate over the results and only extract the relevant comments associated with the specified author.

Comment: Do you mean after this find and projection query, I do a unwind and run another find query with author="authorX"? Because currently, the find and projection will give all the comments by authorX as well any other comment posted on that blog post. Is that correct?

Comment: @Dude - I'm not sure what language you are using to query the DB, but in javascript (in the mongo shell for example), you can perform a `foreach` on the cursor. I've added a simple example to my answer.